# How to extract specific node values without travesing via xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmllint, xmlstarlet

```xml
<xml>
    <email>asdadw@cutshort.io</email>
    <email>sadfasd@cutshort.io</email>
    <email>asdas@cutshort.io</email>
    <host>
        <ip>56.456.155.423, 54.455.155.654, 544.47.745.80, 54.192.155.842</ip>
        <hostname>abc.cutshort.io</hostname>
    </host>
    <host>cdn.cutshort.io</host>
    <host>
        <ip>56.456.155.423, 54.455.155.654, 544.47.745.80, 54.192.155.842</ip>
        <hostname>abc.cutshort.io</hostname>
    </host>
    <host>www.cutshort.io</host>
    <host>blogdata.cutshort.io</host>
    <host>cdn.cutshort.io</host>
</xml>
```

I want to extract the value of "host" without extracting the value of "hostname" or "ip". The output is supposed to look like this:

```
cdn.cutshort.io
www.cutshort.io
blogdata.cutshort.io
cdn.cutshort.io
```

I have only recently started xml parsing so please be patient. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest to always include what you have tried to actually solve the problem yourself.
At the website of xmlstarlet you can download the documentation. Look for the section of `sel` which is called **2. Select/Query XML documents**. There you find anything you need the query your xml.

Comment: Yes sure :D, will do !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the values of the `host` XPATHs that do not have a `hostname` attribute:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//host[not(hostname)]' -n file.xml
cdn.cutshort.io
www.cutshort.io
blogdata.cutshort.io
cdn.cutshort.io
```

(`//host[not(ip)]` would do equally well here).

Comment: Or `'//host[not(./*)]'` to exclude hosts with any descendants.

Comment: @thanasisp thanks - I didn't realize it accepted wildcards - that's good to know